# Ominous message from Chrome ToolBox installer

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

```
"Confirm Installation - 

It can access:
-All data on your computer and the websites you visit"
```

Is anyone else getting this message when attempting to install it.  Trying to figure out if I have a virus.

Also, with some other Chrome extensions today, the download file is a long series of random letters , e.g. "sdfikhsdfkjhwertoiusdifhwesirtiuerkerjkt.crx. Maybe that's normal and I just haven't noticed it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal. The 32 letters are the extension's ID. Nothing to worry about.

If you're really suspicious, follow the following steps:

1. Extract the `.crx` file, e.g. using [7 zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).
2. After extracting, you see another compressed (`.7z`) file.
3. Extract this file as well.
4. You will now see the source code of the extension.
   Check the contents of [`manifest.json`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html). The `It can access:` message is caused by the requested [permissions](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions). See the linked source for more information on each individual permission.

Comment: PS. More technical information about the `.crx` file format can be found [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/crx.html).

Comment: Thanks. Can you possibly confirm you get that same warning.  Just google "Chrome ToolBox" and then hit "Add To Chrome".  I found it strange considering its supposedly written by Google, and what average user would go ahead and install something saying that.

Comment: Also I googled that message and was getting only one substantive web page discussion on it, and the guy posting question about it seemed to have a virus as well:  http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/report-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help/iaLuAtjbWpQ

Comment: To expand on "this is normal": It is not unusual for extensions to ask for this level of permissions but you should only install extensions that you trust with the level of access they are requesting. For example TooBox is made by Google so you can likely trust it but if John Doe creates an extension with the same permissions you may not want to install it.

Comment: @Mark Really, this behaviour is **normal**. A confirmation dialog only improves security. Verified extensions in the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/) are usually safe. If you do not trust the extension, do not install it. For a full list on the meaning of the warnings, see **[Warnings and their triggers](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/permission_warnings.html)**